# creating EBS volumn from and attaching to the same instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

Is it possible to create a EBS volume from and attach it to the same instance? will boto be of some help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is. Set your credentials as environment variables (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`), install `boto` and fire up Python:

```
 >>> import boto
 >>> ec2 = boto.connect_ec2()
 >>> reservations = ec2.get_all_instances()
 >>> ins = reservations.instances[0]        # say ins is *this* instance
 >>> vol = ec2.create_volume(10, ins.placement)
 >>> vol.attach(inst.id, '/dev/sdh')
 u'attaching'
```

The above assumes you have only one instance started. If you know your instance id (you should!) you can simply match on the instance ids over all instances for all reservations.

Eventually you can simply format your volume and mount it:

```
 # mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sdh
 # mkdir /volume
 # mount -t ext3 /dev/sdh /volume
```

Comment: Don't you need to wait for the instance to be available before you can attach it?

Comment: How do you know the mount point (/dev/sdh)?

Answer (score 0):

I think getting the instance ID dynamically is a better option. You can improve the above script with a GET request to the following URL within the instance.

```
http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/instance-id
```

Then you can write one script that'll work for all instances. Even if you just have one at a time, you can include this script in a custom AMI so each new instance can give itself a new volume if needed.